# Download files via php script

Tags: php, caching, memory, download

I'm using this script for downloading files on server via php with 1 connection and resume.
everything is ok but when more than 10 users download in the same time our host can't response other requests.
Physical Memory Usage for 10 users : 739/2000 MB
Entry Processes : 10/70
resources are ok but I think it is because of server cache
please help me ...
thanks

```
<?php
usleep(rand(0,1000000));

function aborts()
{
$file=$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
mysql_query("DELETE FROM downloading where file='$file' and ip='$ip'");
$vars = array_keys(get_defined_vars());
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeOf($vars); $i++) {
    unset($$vars[$i]);
}
unset($vars,$i);
ob_end_clean();
ob_clean();
exit;
}

if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'a.php')){
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
echo 'File Not Found !';
exit;

}
if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Enter Your Account"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    exit;
} else {

function getout($ha){
$hash    = md5($ha);
$chars16 = array(
    '0' => 0,  '1' => 1,  '2' => 2,  '3' => 3, '4' => 4,  '5' => 5,
    '6' => 6,  '7' => 7,  '8' => 8,  '9' => 9, 'a' => 10, 'b' => 11,
    'c' => 12, 'd' => 13, 'e' => 14, 'f' => 15
);
$base10 = '0';
for ($i = strlen($hash) - 1; $i > 0; $i--) {
    $base10 = bcadd($base10, bcmul($chars16[$hash[$i]], bcpow(16, $i)));
}
$chars   = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ,;.:-_+*?!$%&@#~^=/<>[](){}`';
$base    = (string)strlen($chars);
$baseX   = '';
while (bccomp($base10, $base) === 1 || bccomp($base10, $base) === 0) {
    $baseX  = substr($chars, bcmod($base10, $base), 1) . $baseX;
    $base10 = preg_replace('/\.\d*$/', '', bcdiv($base10, $base));
}
$baseX = substr($chars, $base10, 1) . $baseX;
return $baseX;
}

$u=$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
$p=getout($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']);

mysql_connect('localhost','x','x');
mysql_select_db('x');

$go = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accounts where username='$u' and password='$p'");
$number = mysql_num_rows($go);

if($number>0){
$go = mysql_query("SELECT expire FROM accounts where username='$u' and password='$p'");
$data=mysql_fetch_array($go);
$expire=$data[0];
}else{
if(strpos('!'. file_get_contents('../.htpasswd'),$u)){
header('Location: http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . str_replace('bPzID/','',str_replace('/highspeed/','/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])));
exit;
};
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Enter Your DownloadRooz Account"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
exit;
}
if($expire>time()){
header('Location: http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . str_replace('/highspeed/','/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
exit;
};
header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
exit;
$file=$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$go = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM downloading where file='$file' and ip='$ip'");
$number = mysql_num_rows($go);

if($number>0){
exit;

}else{

register_shutdown_function('aborts');

mysql_query("INSERT INTO downloading (file,ip,connections,vip) VALUES ('$file','$ip',1,0)");

$file_path  =  '.' . str_replace('%20',' ',str_replace('/highspeed/','/',str_replace('%28','(',str_replace('%29',')',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))));
$path_parts = pathinfo($file_path);
$file_name  = $path_parts['basename'];
$file_ext   = $path_parts['extension'];

// allow a file to be streamed instead of sent as an attachment
$is_attachment = isset($_REQUEST['stream']) ? false : true;

// make sure the file exists
if (is_file($file_path))
{
    $file_size  = filesize($file_path);
    $file = @fopen($file_path,"rb");
    if ($file)
    {
        // set the headers, prevent caching
        header("Pragma: public");
        header("Expires: -1");
        header("Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file_name\"");

        // set appropriate headers for attachment or streamed file
        if ($is_attachment)
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file_name\"");
        else
                header('Content-Disposition: inline;');

        // set the mime type based on extension, add yours if needed.
        $ctype_default = "application/octet-stream";
        $content_types = array(
                "exe" => "application/octet-stream",
                "zip" => "application/zip",
                "mp3" => "audio/mpeg",
                "mpg" => "video/mpeg",
                "avi" => "video/x-msvideo",
        );
        $ctype = isset($content_types[$file_ext]) ? $content_types[$file_ext] : $ctype_default;
        header("Content-Type: " . $ctype);

        //check if http_range is sent by browser (or download manager)
        if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
        {
            list($size_unit, $range_orig) = explode('=', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 2);
            if ($size_unit == 'bytes')
            {
                //multiple ranges could be specified at the same time, but for simplicity only serve the first range
                //http://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-http-range-retrieval-00.txt
                list($range, $extra_ranges) = explode(',', $range_orig, 2);
            }
            else
            {
                $range = '';
                header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
                exit;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $range = '';
        }

        //figure out download piece from range (if set)
        list($seek_start, $seek_end) = explode('-', $range, 2);

        //set start and end based on range (if set), else set defaults
        //also check for invalid ranges.
        $seek_end   = (empty($seek_end)) ? ($file_size - 1) : min(abs(intval($seek_end)),($file_size - 1));
        $seek_start = (empty($seek_start) || $seek_end < abs(intval($seek_start))) ? 0 : max(abs(intval($seek_start)),0);

        //Only send partial content header if downloading a piece of the file (IE workaround)
        if ($seek_start > 0 || $seek_end < ($file_size - 1))
        {
            header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
            header('Content-Range: bytes '.$seek_start.'-'.$seek_end.'/'.$file_size);
            header('Content-Length: '.($seek_end - $seek_start + 1));
        }
        else
          header("Content-Length: $file_size");
 set_time_limit(19);
        header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

        fseek($file, $seek_start);
        while(!feof($file)) 
        {
if(connection_aborted==1){
mysql_query("DELETE FROM downloading where file='$file' and ip='$ip'");
$vars = array_keys(get_defined_vars());
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeOf($vars); $i++) {
    unset($$vars[$i]);
}
unset($vars,$i);
ob_end_clean();
ob_clean();
exit;
}
usleep(100000);
            print(@fread($file,2400));
            ob_flush();
            flush();
            if (connection_status()!=0) 
            {
@fclose($file);
mysql_query("DELETE FROM downloading where file='$file' and ip='$ip'");
$vars = array_keys(get_defined_vars());
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeOf($vars); $i++) {
    unset($$vars[$i]);
}
unset($vars,$i);
ob_end_clean();
ob_clean();
exit;
            }           
        }
        // file save was a success
        @fclose($file);
        aborts();
        exit;
    }
    else 
    {
        // file couldn't be opened
        header("HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error");
        exit;
    }
}
}
}
?>
```

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: AhleDL, it's better for you to use more precise title for your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I do on [prohackr112.tk](http://prohackr112.tk):

```
<?php
$file = "yoursite.com/" . $_GET['file'];

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
?>
```

Replace `yoursite.com` with your website name and this will download the file from `file` in the URL.